# How to define "..." (finite many steps) in first-order logic?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Suppose the elementary number theory and "$\forall x$ means "for all natural number $x$"."

I thought it was easy to define "infinite" $\exists \omega \forall x \mathord{<}x\omega$ and $\mathord{\neg}\exists x \mathord{<} \omega x$ or $\mathord{\neg}\exists x \mathord{=} S\omega x$.

Then we can define a finite positive number $n$ by $\exists n\,
\mathord{\wedge}
\mathord{<}0n
\mathord{<}n\omega$.

However, I had a hard time figuring out how to define the meaning of finite many steps, namely $\{1,2,...,n\}$. Since $...$ was nowhere defined in the first-order logic, where, in a sense,  I felt $...$ was an abbreviation for induction principle.

My question was that:

1. How could I say "not infinity" without using cardinal number $\omega$?
2. How to say $...$ (finite many steps)?

Comment: $\exists\omega.\forall x.x < \omega$ is false given the usual properties of $<$. In particular, this asserts that $\omega < \omega$ which is usually false by definition of $<$.

Comment: Are you asking how to express this in logical notation within the setting of set theory, or if we're talking about some other language/theory.

Comment: @Derek Elkins I was kind of "cheatingly" assume there was definition about $x$ such that $x$ was a subset (nature number set) of the universe. The simplest fix would be adding $\rightarrow\neg = \omega x $ after $\forall x$.

Comment: @Malice Vidrine Just the first-order language. I found myself using $...$ as taken granted. I was wondering if there is some way to express it in the first-order language.

Comment: There's no such thing as "the" first order language. The languages of groups, of set theory, of Peano arithmetic, are all different languages with differing levels of expressive power.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First-order logic in general **does not** have the ability to say "finitely many" - this is a consequence of the [compactness theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compactness_theorem). One easy consequence of compactness is that if $T$ is any first-order theory with arbitrarily large finite models, then $T$ has infinite models. *(The converse does not hold.)*

(There are other senses in which first-order logic is bad at talking about cardinalities - a fundamental one, and a good contrast to compactness, is the [Lowenheim-Skolem theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6wenheim%E2%80%93Skolem_theorem).)

---

Now in some contexts we can talk about finiteness: e.g. if $M$ is a transitive model of ZFC set theory, then there *is* a first-order formula $\varphi$ such that the set of things in $M$ satisfying $\varphi$ are exactly the finite sets. But that's a very specific situation.