# Specifying an Arbitrary or a Changing Number of Quantifiers in a Definition

Tags: logic, definition, quantifiers

In certain set definitions, it may be necessary to be able to assert an arbitrary number of quantifiers in your definitions. Sometimes, it might even be necessary to suggest that the number of quantifiers may range from one number to another. However, it is not really clear to me how that could be rigorously implied in our definition.

Part 1:

For instance take the definition of the product of n subsets $H_1, H_2 ..., H_n$ of a group G. I understand this definition can be done inductively, but that is besides the point. I'm merely showcasing this concept as an example for cases where substituting this definition with an inductive one might not be possible($\mathbb{*}$) . Let n be an arbitrary natural number

$H_1...H_n= \{x| \underbrace{(\exists h_1 \in H_1)(\exists h_2 \in H_2)...(\exists h_n \in H_n)}_{\text{n times}}(h_1..h_n = x) \}$

How does one specify the "..." within the definition above? We are currently able to define $H_1H_2$, $H_1H_2H_3$, $H_1H_2H_3H_4$ and so one, if we need to. But the general definition for **any n** seems impossible to me, currently.

part 2:

How do we specify a "changing number of quantifiers" in a definition? I'll alter the above definition to a new (and meaningless in Group theory) definition to showcase my point. I'll just call the set S:

$S := \{x| \underbrace{(\exists h_i \in H_i)(\exists h_{i+1} \in H_{i+1})...(\exists h_j \in H_j)}_{1 \leq i \leq j \leq n}(h_i..h_j = x) \}$

How can one describe such concept, precisely?

I'm very new to logic, but I'm aware the answers to these questions depend highly on what language we are working with. So, I suppose a better question would be to ask if there is a language in which answers exist to my above questions. And if so, what are those answers?

($\mathbb{*}$) I mentioned that an inductive solution to part 1's example is not of interest here, but I am curious if an inductive solution could be applied to **any case** in which part 1's (and part 2's) problem occurs.
Also, if we do inductive definitions here, we are doing it on quantifiers; Is this something done within our metalanguage? Is it even allowed?

I'd be most thankful for your guidance.

Comment: I think the answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2480831/how-to-define-finite-many-steps-in-first-order-logic) question might also be relevant here.

Comment: Thank you so much for kindly replying. Even if it wasn't exactly relevant (I'll get the chance to check it out later), this was another question that had been bothering me before for so long. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

First case:

$\exists n\geq 1\forall i\in\{1,\ldots,n\} \exists h_i \in H_i : \prod_{j=1}^n h_j = x$

Comment: That's true. Is it possible to generalize this if each of the n quantifiers contain a different formula with no apparent pattern connecting them? I.e. $\phi_1(x), ... \phi_n(x)$?

Comment: Not sure what you mean here.

Comment: I mean $\{ x| (\exists \phi_1(y)) ...(\exists \phi_n(y)) (\phi_{n+1}(x,y)) \}$. If we had such a statement in the description that was not specific to any context, can we still write it precisely in a similar fashion to the way you did?

Comment: Here you need to specify $y$ (exits or for all)? Otherwise, its a free variable.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean. For example $\exists \phi_i(y)$ would mean $(\exists 1 \leq y \leq 3)$, if $\phi_i(y) = 1 \leq y \leq 3$. It's a stand in for a formula based on y, where y is the bound variable we are working with.